# Property of a locally compact Hausdorff topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a locally compact and Hausdorff topological space;  let $A$ be a compact subspace of $Y$, and $B$ an open subset of $Y$ conteining $A$.
How can I find an open set $U$ (open in $Y$) and a compact space $K$ such that $$A\subset U\subset K\subset B\subset Y?$$

Comment: Every $x\in A$ has a compact neighbourhood $N_x$ with $N_x \subset B$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. Why?  Every $x$ in $A$ has an open neighbourhood conteined in $B$ whose closure is compact.  How can I be sure there are open neighbourhood conteined in $B$ whose closure is compact and also conteined in $B$?

Comment: It seems that in your book/course, neighbourhoods are defined as open? That makes for a somewhat more cumbersome terminology. Nevertheless, the key fact is that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact, and $\overline{V}\subset U$. (If neighbourhoods aren't required to be open, that could be simply stated as: the compact neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis at each point.) a) Given that, do you know how to prove your goal? b) Is that fact known, or something you still have to prove?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. My neighbourhoods are not required to be open.  My definition of locally compact is that for every point there is an open subset with compact closure which contains the point.  How do I get to what you stated?  Yes, if I get to this I know then how to proceed

Comment: Okay. Since supersets of neighbourhoods are again neighbourhoods, and an open set containing $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, the definition can be rephrased as "each point has a closed compact neighbourhood". In Hausdorff spaces, compact subsets are closed, so there we can state it as "every point has a compact neighbourhood". Now what we need to do is deduce that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, the compact neighbourhoods form a neighbourhood basis at each point, or, phrased differently, every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, every neighbourhood of a point $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood of $x$. Since if $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, then the interior $\overset{\Large\circ}{N}$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$, we may assume that our neighbourhood is open.

So let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $x\in X$, and $U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$. Let $K$ be a compact neighbourhood of $x$, as guaranteed by local compactness. Since $U$ is open, $C := K \setminus U$ is a compact set, and since $x\in U$, we have $x \notin C$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, for every $y \in C$ there are disjoint open neighbourhoods $V_y$ of $x$ and $W_y$ of $y$. Since $C$ is compact, and $$C \subset \bigcup_{y\in C} W_y,$$

there are finitely many points $y_1,\dotsc, y_n \in C$ with

$$C \subset \bigcup_{k = 1}^n W_{y_k}.$$

Then

$$V := \overset{\Large\circ}{K} \cap U \cap \bigcap_{k = 1}^n V_{y_k}$$

is an open neighbourhood of $x$. We have $V \subset K$, so $\overline{V}$ is compact (and contained in $K$). By construction,

$$\overline{V} \cap \bigcup_{k = 1}^n W_{y_k} = \varnothing,$$

so $\overline{V}\cap C = \varnothing$, whence $\overline{V}\subset K \setminus C = K \cap U \subset U$.

---

Then cover $A$ by finitely many open sets whose closure is compact and contained in $B$.